# custom docker image is not running postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, circleci

I am trying to create my own custom docker file for circleci v2. however, I am running into an issue where the postgres server is not running. I've run `service postgresql start` to no available.

the message I'm getting is:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV NODEJS_VERSION 6
ENV POSTGRESQL_VERSION 9.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODEJS_VERSION.x | bash -
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y \
  nodejs \
  make \
  git \
  g++ \
  python-software-properties \
  software-properties-common \
  postgresql-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION \
  postgresql-client-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION \
  postgresql-contrib-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION

RUN echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" >> /etc/postgresql/$POSTGRESQL_VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/$POSTGRESQL_VERSION/main/postgresql.conf

USER postgres
RUN service postgresql start && \
  psql -c "create database pgdb;" && \
  psql -c "create role pgrole with login password 'pgrole'; grant all privileges on database pgdb to pgrole;"
```

See also:

- GitHub: https://github.com/jonathanong/docker-nodejs-postgres
- CircleCI: https://circleci.com/gh/jonathanong/docker-nodejs-postgres/tree/master

thanks

Answer (score 2):

## The problem

The issue is that you don't define which command your image should run, so it defaults to the command that was set in the Ubuntu base image: `/bin/bash`.

Take a look at the documentation for [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> **Note:** Don’t confuse `RUN` with `CMD`. `RUN` actually runs a command and commits the result; `CMD` does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image.

So your `RUN service postgresql start` is executed at **build time**, and the result of that command is committed to the image as a layer. When you start the image, e.g. on CircleCI, the `CMD` for the image is executed. And since you didn't set that, it uses the one that Ubuntu specified: `/bin/bash`. Which means at **runtime**, there is in fact to Postgres running.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the `CMD` must not be a daemon. Docker keeps a container running as long as a process is executed in the foreground, so if you do `CMD service postgresql start`, Docker will exit the container after the command has returned.

## The solution

I recommend that you redo your whole CI setup. If you start Postgres in the `CMD`, you can't overwrite that command to run your tests (or Postgres wouldn't be running again).

Instead, use two images, one for your app and one for Postgres. You start Postgres, wait for it to accept connections and then in your `app` container run the tests.

You can reuse the existing `postgresql` image, which creates a database and user for you when you start it. You need to add a script to wait for the database to be ready, or your tests will run before the database is accepting connections. See this post: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/waiting-for-database/10946

With this approach, it is much easier to run multiple services at once and still have complete freedom over which commands you want to run on Circle CI.

## The alternative

A little bit easier, but just for testing, is the option to create an entrypoint that starts Postgres and waits for it to be ready. Create a script, copy it in the `Dockerfile` and point the `ENTRYPOINT` to it. In the script, run `services postgresql start`, create your database and then wait for Postgres to accept connections. Once that is done, use `exec $@` to execute whatever command you pass to the container.

You can find a script that we use to wait for Postgres here: https://gist.github.com/jdno/09377bde65095773e5daf1aaa8e62ef4

This script can easily be extended to serve as an `ENTRYPOINT` as well.

- Start Postgres with `services postgresql start`.
- Wait for Postgres to accept connections (i.e. what the script does now).
- Run `psql` commands to create your database.
- End the script with `exec $@` to execute the Docker `CMD`.

This is a little bit easier to set up, but not suited for production.

Comment: I was told by circle support to just make my own image, which is why I am here... I tried using two docker images (node + Postgres), but I need the psql CLI, which isn't provided by Postgres. I think one issue is that I am not waiting. what if I ran the "waiting for Postgres to accept connections" script during the test steps?

Comment: We use `node:alpine` images for our tests, and in their Dockerfiles run `apk add --no-cache postgresql` to get the `pg_isready` executable. We also copy this script here into the image: https://gist.github.com/jdno/09377bde65095773e5daf1aaa8e62ef4. In our tests, we then run steps like this: `./wait-for-services.sh mocha`.

You can use the same script for your `ENTRYPOINT` if you want to stick with a single image, and extend it to create your database. But then, your step would just be `mocha` (or whatever command is used to run the tests).